# How should I name the controller in the following Language Class tutorial (CodeIgniter)?

Tags: class, codeigniter

The following is a great tutorial about using the Language Class. But I think the author forgot about creating the controller file. I just started using CI today and I'm not sure how to name the controller file for the view "example.php".

The tutorial:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Internationalization_and_the_Template_Parser_Class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the tutorial, you should name it `Example`. Basically,controller should have the name as that of the file but first letter capitalized.

**[See Controller docs for more information.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Same as controler class name.